How can I specify to the VSCode ruby-lsp extension to use docker container?
I have rvm installed on my MacBook where I am developing a Ruby on Rails app that is in a Docker Compose environment. I want VSCode's ruby-lsp extension to use the installation of ruby in my container and NOT my rvm installation. The main reason here is that if a ruby version or gem version changes in the Docker container but not on my MacOS, then it breaks ruby-lsp. I also don't want to use VSCode Remote.
I have ruby-lsp installed via my Gemfile.
This is the output from ruby-lsp extension in VSCode:
2024-05-10 15:03:48.953 [info] (cms) Checking if chruby is available on the path with command: /bin/bash -i -c 'chruby --version'
2024-05-10 15:03:49.085 [info] (cms) Checking if rbenv is available on the path with command: /bin/bash -i -c 'rbenv --version'
2024-05-10 15:03:49.200 [info] (cms) Checking if rvm is available on the path with command: /bin/bash -i -c 'rvm --version'
2024-05-10 15:03:49.445 [info] (cms) Discovered version manager rvm
2024-05-10 15:03:49.641 [info] (cms) Activated Ruby environment: NVM_INC=/Users/daerlt/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/include/node MANPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/man: VSCODE_CRASH_REPORTER_PROCESS_TYPE=extensionHost rvm_bin_path=/Users/daerlt/.rvm/bin GEM_HOME=/Users/daerlt/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2 SHELL=/bin/bash HISTSIZE=1000000 HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew IRBRC=/Users/daerlt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/.irbrc TMPDIR=/var/folders/1s/q0gv32zd39l8cgpr7bw748zh0000gp/T/ MallocNanoZone=0 ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=undefined MY_RUBY_HOME=/Users/daerlt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2 HISTFILESIZE=1000000 NVM_DIR=/Users/daerlt/.nvm USER=daerlt COMMAND_MODE=unix2003 rvm_path=/Users/daerlt/.rvm SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZjqvUOBPjt/Listeners __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0x0:0x0 VSCODE_AMD_ENTRYPOINT=vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 rvm_prefix=/Users/daerlt PATH=/Users/daerlt/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin:/Users/daerlt/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@global/bin:/Users/daerlt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/daerlt/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/daerlt/.rvm/bin __CFBundleIdentifier=com.microsoft.VSCode PWD=/Users/daerlt/Whitney/code/topgoose/cms VSCODE_HANDLES_UNCAUGHT_ERRORS=true EDITOR=nano XPC_FLAGS=0x0 XPC_SERVICE_NAME=application.com.microsoft.VSCode.161897059.161897065 rvm_version=1.29.12 (latest) rvm_pretty_print_flag=auto HOME=/Users/daerlt SHLVL=2 APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL=1 VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG={"locale":"en-us","osLocale":"en-us","availableLanguages":{},"_languagePackSupport":true} HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew LOGNAME=daerlt GEM_PATH=/Users/daerlt/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2:/Users/daerlt/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2@global VSCODE_CODE_CACHE_PATH=/Users/daerlt/Library/Application Support/Code/CachedData/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685 VSCODE_IPC_HOOK=/Users/daerlt/Library/Application Support/Code/1.89-main.sock NVM_BIN=/Users/daerlt/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/bin VSCODE_PID=77525 HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info: rvm_delete_flag=0 RUBY_VERSION=ruby-3.2.2 VSCODE_CWD=/
2024-05-10 15:03:49.851 [info] (cms) ruby: warning: Ruby was built without YJIT support. You may need to install rustc to build Ruby with YJIT.

2024-05-10 15:03:50.232 [info] (cms) Ruby LSP> Running bundle install for the custom bundle. This may take a while...
Ruby LSP> Command: (bundle check || bundle install) 1>&2

2024-05-10 15:03:50.244 [info] (cms) ruby: warning: Ruby was built without YJIT support. You may need to install rustc to build Ruby with YJIT.

2024-05-10 15:03:50.362 [info] (cms) Your Ruby version is 3.2.2, but your Gemfile specified ~> 3.3

...

2024-05-10 15:03:51.019 [info] (cms) /Users/daerlt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:426:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 3.2.2, but your Gemfile specified ~> 3.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /Users/daerlt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:401:in `validate_runtime!'


After doing this I tried specifying the ruby command but that also generated an error:
    "rubyLsp.rubyVersionManager": {
        "identifier": "custom"
    },
    "rubyLsp.customRubyCommand": "docker compose exec -T cms /usr/local/bin/ruby"

Automatic Ruby environment activation with custom failed: Command failed: docker compose exec -T cms /usr/local/bin/ruby && ruby -W0 -rjson -e 'STDERR.print({ env: ENV.to_h, yjit: !!defined?(RubyVM::YJIT), version: RUBY_VERSION }.to_json)' stat /Users/.../my_project_root/cms/docker-compose.yml: no such file or directory

Not sure if this is relevant but my docker-compose.yml is at my_project_root and looks like this
services:
  cms:
    init: true
    build:
      context: ./cms
      dockerfile: ../docker/Dockerfile.cms
    volumes:
      - ./cms:/app/cms
      - cms-gems:/usr/local/bundle
      - ./backup:/backup
volumes:
  cms-gems:
    driver: local


Did you end up finding a solution for your problem?

No sadly. I am still using my workaround of running ruby-lsp on the MacBook installation of ruby.
